# streaming an mkv file while processing with ffmpeg

Tags: python, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mkv

**What I want to do:**

- I want to play an mkv video in Firefox.
- But Firefox doesn't support the mkv format.

So I've searched a lot and found that,
I could stream instead of playing the video following these steps.

- mkv can be converted to an m3u8 using FFmpeg
- The m3u8 points towards ts segment files
- then use hls.js on the browser side to play the video

But the catch is I want to do this programmatically.

**What I actually want to do:**

Steps

- the client uploads a huge (>1 GB) mkv file to the client's server (server is the client's machine itself)
- after the upload is done,
- client requests to play the video.
- the server starts transcoding and sends the client the m3u8 stream immediately instead of making the client wait for the transcoding to complete.
- the client should be able to seek the video. (the most IMPORTANT part)

#### It is possible as [Emby](https://emby.media) and [Plex](https://plex.tv) both have implemented it.

I was able to get this to work in chrome as it supports playing some mkv files.
I wrote a node js server that accepts `Range` header and *pseudo-streams* the video.

[A gist](https://gist.github.com/phanirithvij/85271cbf39a3b98cecae22972bca27f0)

But as I've mentioned Firefox says NO to mkv.

So I tried the hls thing but I couldn't quite get the command to generate the stream and also play on the fly.

I started this on a command line

```sh
ffmpeg -i ../stream.mkv -hls_list_size 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy file.m3u8
```

and a simple `http-server` on another shell instance

My index.html file

```html
<html>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <body>
        <script src="./hls.js"></script>
        <video id="video" width="400" controls></video>
        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            if(Hls.isSupported()) {
                var hls = new Hls();
                hls.loadSource('file.m3u8');
                hls.attachMedia(video);
                hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
                    video.play();
                });
            } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
                video.src = 'file.m3u8';
                video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
                    video.play();
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and while it was running I went ahead and requested the server.

I was able to get the video but It only seeks as far it's converted into the ts files.

And it's random and the video length keeps increasing. It won't play sometimes and after the FFmpeg is done converting to m3u8 the video plays if I refresh the webpage.

I think this has to do with the continuous overwriting of the m3u8 file.
is there a way to predetermine the file contents of m3u8 and fill it up?

I want to be able to seek even further and somehow spawn another FFmpeg process
to start from that timestamp of the video? How could I approach the seeking part?

So what I'd like to do again is

- I want to request the server to play a video file
- It spawns a child process FFmpeg that does the transcoding
- Sends the client the stream
- The client should be able to seek to the end and it should play the thing.

Comment: I guess I've clearly explained what help I needed, is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exact problem are you running into? We'd like to help but we aren't here to write the code for you. Additionally, posting a link to Github isn't ideal as we won't quickly be able to see the code at a glance. We also won't have the right version if it gets modified. Instead you might want to take a snippet from your code that's causing a problem and share that in the question.

Comment: I've shared the gist on what I tried. As it seemed the post was getting long. And I'm not asking anyone to write code for me. I want you to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is actually very difficult. Plex is able to cheat because the file is packaged for each user specifically, and for the most part plex control the player.

The way Plex basically works:

The file is pre analyzed, and a complete manifest is generated. Transcode is kicked off a the start of the file and caches the segments locally. If a seek happens (A segment is requested that is not cached locally) the transcode is canceled, and a new on started at the offset of the segment requested, and the player invalidates any segment it has cached.

If the client cached segments are not invalidated, or a CDN is used, there is no guarantee the the first, post seek, segment will align with its previous segment generated at a later time. This will cause skips and pops at the boundary.

For example seek 1hour out into a movie, than skip back 30 seconds. The two segments are created in the wrong order and will not smoothy play back to back

If you need to support off the shelf players and CDNs, the problem is more difficult because you must be able to generate frame accurate segments on the fly. Frame accurate audio is tricky, especially with codecs the use priming samples. I recommend you look into commercial services like [mux.com](http://mux.com) that that do basically this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood that it's complicated if it's a cdn as you mentioned. And I roughly got the idea on what plex is doing. But I'm not sure how I can generate a complete manifest. And how I can handle the offset request that you mentioned. How can I generate a complete manifest is it using `ffprobe`? How can I calculate the number of segments generated before I run the `ffmpeg` command given the duration?

Comment: I want to first replicate what plex/emby does and think about what to do in case of a cdn. And any suggestions on what backend is preferred in this case. Like should I use `node js` with express? Or python with flask?

Comment: I would seguest you locate the keyframes using ffprobe, and assume one segment per keyframe. ffprobe will also give you timestamps for seeking and calculating segment duration.

Comment: Say my video duration is exactly one hour and I set `hls_time` flag to be 6 how many segments can I expect and are each of them of same duration of 6 sec?

Comment: It depends. If you use independent segments, then the length of the video matters less than the number and placement of IDR frames. If you don't need independent segments, and use transpire stream, then splitting on P frames should be ok, and you can do a simple division.